# Change sort order when using 'orderby' => 'type'

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, order

When doing a wp_query with the following parameters:

```
$arg = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'activity', 'publication', 'project', 'course' ),
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'type',
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($arg);
```

It seems that the only order criteria allowed is the alphabetical, ASC or DESC. In this specific case, the order is: activity, course, project and lastly publication.

Is there any way to return the posts in a custom order? For example: "project, publication, activity and course"

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I know about this solution, but it's not what I'm looking for. This specific query it's already involved in a major query loop. I was thinking that maybe filtering the query will do the trick, but no idea on how to get this...

Comment: For me, you don't want to sort the results but group them. Then, you want those groups in a specific order. Think about it.

Comment: @cybmeta You are right, and how to get it?

Comment: Simply use `usort` to sort the returned array of posts. Also, do **not** use `$wp_query` as a local variable as this breaks the main query object

Comment: @pieter-goosen So, we are agree that in short, the answer to my question is: "that's not possible", correct?